# Pandas: Why do I need to do apply lambda instead of nesting functions?

Tags: python, r, pandas, datetime

In order to convert this string column to datetime with the year, month and day I'm doing this:

```
df['date_ymd'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
```

However, looking at the way this code has one function nested in another, and also coming from an `r` programming background, I would expect this, more parsimonious approach to work:

```
df['date_ymd'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

But this returns the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Can anyone explain why this is not possible?

Thanks!

Edited: Here's an example of my data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
           {"date" : [None, '2020-06-13 17:32:55.367081+02:00', '2020-03-26 14:33:26.506618+01:00']},
         index = [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: instead of `apply`, you could do `pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: A pandas Series **can't** implement ALL the method of ALL the types. But you can access some for specific types like `.str` `.dt`

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can take a look at it.  Do you wish to convert None to NaT or does this answer work? If this works then pls accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the object is `Series`. Instead, you can do it in this way by adding `.dt` before `.strftime()` to get `.dt` type:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
       {"date" : [None, '2020-06-13 17:32:55.367081+02:00', '2020-03-26 14:33:26.506618+01:00']},
     index = [1, 2, 3])
df['date_ymd'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], utc = True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Output:

```
                               date    date_ymd
1                              None         NaN
2  2020-06-13 17:32:55.367081+02:00  2020-06-13
3  2020-03-26 14:33:26.506618+01:00  2020-03-26
```

Comment: thanks, so what does `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` become here if it is not a series?

Comment: @stevezissou It's still a series object. try printing its type and contents and you'll find it out!

Comment: thanks, by the way, with your code I get this error: `ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True` do you have any idea what that means?

Comment: @stevezissou Can you provide some samples of your data? You can try `df['date_ymd'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], utc = True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: ok wait, your solution worked on one column, but not another one. The problem with the second one was that there are some 'none' in the column instead of a date expression. It seems to only work if I do it in two steps, like `df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df"date"], utc = True)
df['date_ymd'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: @stevezissou It would be really great if you can provide some sample data for me to reproduce the problem.

Comment: also weird, your method returns an object. If I want to get a datetime back I need to use apply and do it in two steps like: `df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], utc = True)
df['date_ymd'] = df['date_'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))`

Comment: Hey, Now I edited my post with some example data. Thanks

Comment: @stevezissou I have edited my answer. Do you wish to convert `None` to `NaT` or does this answer work?